# Can Scipy.optimize.differential_evolution compute SD or SE of estimated parameters?

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-deviation, standard-error, differential-evolution

I used Scipy.optimize.differential_evolution to estimate parameters for my models; however, unlike Curve_fit, it cannot retire covariance. How can I calculate the uncertainties of my parameters?

Answer (score 2):

You could start off with `differential_evolution` to find the minimum, then follow-up with a `leastsq` or `curve_fit` to estimate the uncertainties. Other ways of estimating the uncertainties are to calculate the Hessian matrix by using e.g. [finite differences](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tools.numdiff.approx_hess2.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I'm confused about 'follow-up with a  leastsq or curve_fit.' since I can get the estimated parameters via  differential_evolution. Do you mean setting these values as initial guesses for curve_fit and then finding the covariance?

Comment: Yes, use the estimated parameters from `differential_evolution` as initial guesses for `curve_fit`, or `leastsq`. Alternatively use the link I provided to directly estimate the Hessian via numerical differentiation. I suspect `curve_fit` or `leastsq` would be the preferred options. `differential_evolution` is unable to calculate the Hessian because it works on a purely stochastic basis, without gradients.